# Magento - list specific cms page link in left hand block

Tags: php, magento

I want to list specific CMS pages LINKS to lefthand side of block in magento.
eg. suppose i have added 10 cms pages in admin and now i want to list 2 to 3 specific cmspages which i want. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this task using **Widgets** -

**Process 1:** We can add Widgets for specific CMS page as "CMS Page Link".
Magento provides the facility to add many kind of Widgets.

**Process 2:** We can create a Static block where we can put the Code for Link of CMS pages.
And we can call this Static Block using Widget on Left/Right Column or the position where we want.

Hope it'll be Helpful :)

Thanks.